# Reusing the options menu xml - is it good practice

Tags: android, options-menu

Is it considered good practice to use the same options menu in multiple activities?

For example:

You have a number of "edit object" activities, with each activity accommodating a different object. The options menu in "edit object" activities would allow the user to save, discard (if the user is adding a new item) or delete (if editing) an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have same menu for every object use it. There is not reason to have x same files if you don't need it. And when you want change something it's easier in one file like in many files.